# maintaining data consistency in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, repository, spring-data-jpa

I have a scenario where I have to insert data into multiple tables. If one query fails then I want to rollback the last executed query

My Service method is

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ServiceNameImpl implements ServiceName{
    @Autowired
    private ABCRepository abcRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCDRepository bcdRepository;

    @Override
    public SChResource save(SchData schData){
        SchSch sch = new SchSch();
        Contact con = new Contact();
        sch.setName(schData.getName());
        abcRepository.save(sch);  --first insertion
        con.setAddress(schData.getAddress());
        bcdRepository.save(con);  --second insertion
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want if first insertion executes and second insertion fail then the first insertion will rollback and if first insertion fails and second insertion executes then second insertion will rollback.

Please suggest me what should I do.

Comment: Looks like you want to make your `save()` method transactional.

Comment: That should already work as your service is `@Transactional` if it isn't working then this question contains too little information to answer your question.

Comment: @M. Deinum I am confused with what should I use @Transaction(readOnly=true) or @Transactional(readOnly=false).Because there are some other methods in this service class whom i don't want to make transactional

Comment: @Kayaman Yeah I want to make my save method transactional. But there are some other method in this service class whom i don't want to make transactional

Comment: I didn't tell you to make the other methods transactional, did I? Put the annotation on the method and not the class. Then read the documentation so you won't have to be confused with how Spring works.

Comment: thanx  should i remove the @transactional annotation from my class and make the method transactional

Comment: Have you tried annotating specific method with @Transactional(rollbackFor = YourException.class)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Spring data Jpa and extending `JpaRepository` or its super or child class in your `ABCRepository` and `BCDRepository`.

In that case you also need to add `@EnableTransactionManagement` on any of of your class which has `@Configuration` on it.

Comment: Yeah I am extending JpaRepository, but didn't get the second point you have mentioned

Comment: Are you using EnableTransactionManagement annotation, if not use it then it should work, You can use this method on any class which have Configuration annotation on it.

Comment: May be in your applicationcontext.xml file you are missing annotation driven transaction activation. `<tx:annotation-driven/>`

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for `@Transactional` annotation. You should to use from package `org.springframework.transaction.annotation`, not from `javax.transaction`. It doesn't appear in the code snippet you pasted, but I ran into this mistake in the past, that's why i thought this is the case here.